# How can I put my CentOS on public IP so that I can access it WinSCP from home?

Tags: linux, networking, centos

I have a centOS system at office and I want to access it from home via WinSCP. I have a static public IP at office. Please help!

Comment: You need to configure your office router to port forward/trigger as appropriate from the public ip to the private ip of the centos machine. Perhaps your office IT department can help with this?

Comment: Wll port forwarding alone will work? Also my company is a startup and I am my company's IT department. Please guide me.

Comment: Yes, port forwarding should work. http://portforward.com/ will tell you everything you need to know. It has detailed instructions for many routers and programs.

Comment: Everyone seems to assume a private IP on the office PCs. This is certainly most common, but it could have a 'normal IP'. In which case it just should work assuming **no firewall** blocks it.

Comment: Having said that: `I have a static public IP at office` could indeed mean "I got **ONE** static puplic IP and it is on the router, from where I NAT".

Answer (score 0):

As @David mentioned above in the comment (which I think should go as an answer), you need to forward your port, but what port depends on the protocol you want to use. Below are some ports you might want to use

- SSH - 22
- RDP - 3389
- FTP - 21 (standard port - not advisable - use SFTP instead)

But since you want to use WinSCP, you should go with port 22.

Comment: Might want to add some more info to FTP because: 1) It uses a lot more ports (21 is just the command port).  2) Please do not use it over the internet. PLAIN TEXT PASSWORDS. UNSAFE! UNCLEAN! ...

Answer (score 0):

#### I have a centOS system at office and I want to access it from home via WinSCP

You need to configure your office router to port forward/port trigger as appropriate from the public (external) IP address of the office internet connection to the private intgernal) IP address of the Centos machine.

Notes

- The instructions for doing this are a little different for each make/model of router.
- http://www.portforward.com will tell you everything you need to know.

  It has detailed instructions for many routers and programs.
- SCP runs on TCP port 22 by default.
- You will, of course need to have an SCP server running on the Centos machine.